# Django + Modelos a partir de base de datos existente

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Hola estoy trabajando en un proyecto que tengo una base de datos en postgresql y mi cliente necesita que tambien trabaje con una base de datos existente en sql server que tiene unas 150 tablas de las cual solo me hacen falta unas 20, mi pregunta es **¿Se puede crear el modelo de solo mas 20 tablas utilizando inspectdb ?** Saludos

Comment: No veo por que no, `inspectdb` te crearía un `models.py` correspondiente a las 150 tablas, simplemente deberías editarlo y dejar las tablas que realmente te interesen.

Comment: si, pero no se puede hacer solo para unas tablas especificas , no todas

Comment: Según la documentación https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-inspectdb, pareciera que sí.